# How can I display text over toolbar button for a firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to display a small text (new messages count) over icon in toolbar button, something like Chrome and Opera extensions have with badge over the toolbar icons. Text should not cover the whole icon, it should be at the bottom so the user can still see main part of the icon and recognize what extension it is. How can I do this?

You can see what I want on this example image from Chrome:

[image: toolbar button text overlay on chrome]

I tried with description, span and div inside stack element but I couldn't get none of them to position at the bottom. Description and div always display text at the center, while span displays it on the right side of the icon making the entire button wider.

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton class="toolbarbutton-1">
        <stack>
            <image></image>
            <description right="0" bottom="0" value="4"></description>
            <!-- <html:div right="0" bottom="0">5</html:div> -->
        </stack>
    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had some time to waste while waiting for rain to stop in Formula 1, so I made this work with canvas:

**UPDATED**: Previous method was flawed when user would remove the icon from the toolbar, updated method is more robust and with less code.

### XUL

```
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <hbox hidden="true">
        <html:canvas id="toolbar_button_canvas" width="24" height="24"></html:canvas>
    </hbox>
    <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
        <toolbarbutton id="toolbar_button" class="toolbarbutton-1" />
    </toolbarpalette>
</overlay>
```

### CSS

```
#toolbar_button {
    list-style-image:url("chrome://your_extension/skin/icon_024.png");
}

toolbar[iconsize="small"] #toolbar_button {
    list-style-image:url("chrome://your_extension/skin/icon_016.png");
}
```

### JavaScript

```
show_status: function(display_text)
{
    var btn = document.getElementById("toolbar_button");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("toolbar_button_canvas");
    var img_src = window.getComputedStyle(btn).listStyleImage.replace(/^url\("(chrome:\/\/your_extension\/skin\/icon_0\d{2}.png)"\)$/, "$1");   // get image path
    var csize = img_src.replace(/^chrome:\/\/your_extension\/skin\/icon_0(\d{2})\.png$/, "$1"); // get image size

    canvas.setAttribute("width", csize);
    canvas.setAttribute("height", csize);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function()
    {
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        ctx.font = "bold 9px sans-serif";       // has to go before measureText

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        if (display_text !== "")
        {
            var w = ctx.measureText(display_text).width;
            var h = 7;                  // 9 = font height

            var rp = ((canvas.width - 4) > w) ? 2 : 1;  // right padding = 2, or 1 if text is wider
            var x = canvas.width - w - rp;
            var y = canvas.height - h - 1;          // 1 = bottom padding

            ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";             // background color
            ctx.fillRect(x-rp, y-1, w+rp+rp, h+2);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";             // text color
            ctx.fillText(display_text, x, y);
            //ctx.strokeText(display_text, x, y);
        }
        btn.image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", "");  // set new toolbar image
    };
    img.src = img_src;
}
```

Comment: I can't get it working, it says `canvas is null`. My script calling this method is in the end of the page

Comment: How do you get the button to display the canvas once you've drawn on it? I guess I'm missing something obvious, but the canvas is in a hidden hbox so it won't be visible.

Comment: @MatthewGertner You are right, I accidentally omitted some very important parts of code, I updated the answer so please try again.

Comment: Sometimes, on load FF, broken update for image property. Its destroy work of code: 'btn.image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", "");'. Property has changed, but icon stay old. For this fix you need append after that line this line: 'btn.style.listStyleImage = "url('" + btn.image + "')";' - its fix issue.

Comment: btn.style.listStyleImage is not enough. Full version: `var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", ""); btn.image = image; btn.setAttribute('image', image); btn.style.listStyleImage = "url('" + image + "')";` It replace for line `btn.image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", "");`

Answer (score 2):

my variant with html:div

P.S. you can also try play with z-index

How it's looks http://f3.s.qip.ru/fTUvr2Cj.jpg

## XUL

```
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <toolbar id="nav-bar">
    <hbox>
    <html:div style="color: #000000;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 16px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;">5</html:div>
    <toolbarbutton  insertafter="search-container" type="menu">
    <menupopup>
    <menuitem   class="menuitem-iconic" label="&count;"></menuitem>

    <menuitem   class="menuitem-iconic" label="&size;"></menuitem>

    <menuitem  class="menuitem-iconic" label="&time;"></menuitem>
    <menuseparator></menuseparator>
    <menuitem  class="menuitem-iconic" label="&settings;"></menuitem>
    </menupopup>
    </toolbarbutton>
    </hbox>
    </toolbar>
</overlay>
```

Comment: In many ways, this variant is cleaner than Igor's variant (e.g., it naturally handles images that have hover states).  However, fixed positioning is relative to the browser window, which makes this much more difficult to use if your button is not the rightmost or leftmost button.  During my own testing, I found that this issue could be resolved by setting the parent hbox to `style="position:relative;"` and the position of the `html:div` to `position: absolute;` A purist can replace `html:div` with `hbox` (or `vbox` or `box`); it still seems to work.

Comment: I also recommend adding `pointer-events: none;` to the style of the div.  This causes mouse interaction (cursor image and clicks) to fall through to the `toolbarbutton`.

Comment: For anyone else looking for the same. This solution really works. Other than the points noted by above commentators, following also need to be done as of Firefox 25:

Comment: 1. If the parent is a ````hbox````, it becomes impossible to remove the button using customize toolbar dialog. The parent element should be ````toolbaritem````.

2. The parent must have an id if you need firefox to show the button after browser restart.

I will link to the code I am using as soon as I publish it on github

Answer (score 2):

I just used the libraries from **[browser-action-jplib](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib)**

And it worked fine on my  **[simple addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/facebook-like-all/)**

If you use the library, you may got some problems with AMO-review

It can be solved by the **[issue](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/issues/13)**